# Custom element does not render in portal window

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I want to be able to detach a react component into a new window such that it would stay connected to the main logic (to show students a window with only the simulation on the projector while I can see and edit both the code that is running the simulation and the simulation itself in a window on my computer).

I was able to detach the window such that it would do just that, the problem is that the simulation elements do not render in the newly created window and I do not know how to fix it.

Here is a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/dawn-sky-q3hht2?file=/src/Detachable.tsx) illustrating the problem.

I don't know what could be the cause of the problem. I am new to web technologies so the problem may be something obvious / trivial. I just can't figure it out. Thank you.